# Using out-of-sequence tags in XSLT (or grouping elements)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is it possible to have out-of-sequence tags within XSLT using 1.0?  My initial guess is not, as it breaks the rules of XML.

Consider XML data that has X elements, and I want to split those X entries into blocks of 3 within individual `<div>` blocks.  What I would **like** to do is something this, but obviously it is completely invalid code...

```
<div>
  <xsl:for-each select="mydata">
    <xsl:value-of select="myvalue"/><br/>
    <xsl:if test="(position() mod 3)=0">
      </div> <!-- This is invalid -->
      <div> <!-- This is invalid -->
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

So for 8 elements, the example result would be

```
<div>
  value1<br/>
  value2<br/>
  value3<br/>
</div>
<div>
  value4<br/>
  value5<br/>
  value6<br/>
</div>
<div>
  value7<br/>
  value8<br/>
</div>
```

If the above is simply not possible (as I suspect it is not), can somebody suggest an acceptable way to group them like this?

(Please note, this must be an XSLT 1.0 solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do *is* possible, but it isn't a good idea.  This is a better approach:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="mydata[position() mod 3 = 1]" mode="group" />

<!-- Separate templates -->
<xsl:template match="mydata" mode="group">
  <div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::mydata[position() &lt; 3]" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mydata">
  <xsl:value-of select="myvalue"/><br/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That's great - many thanks JLRishe.  And congratulations on your 10k :-D

Answer (score 2):

JLRishe shows you the solution.

Your problem is that you are thinking of your stylesheet as writing start and end tags. That's not what XSLT does: it writes a tree. You can't write half a node to the result tree. Think nodes, not tags.

When you have problems like this in which the output structure doesn't exactly match the input structure, another useful rule of thumb is that the structure of the stylesheet should reflect the tree structure of the output, not that of the input. Don't think "what shall I do with the next ABC input node", but rather "I need to generate an XYZ node in the result tree, how shall I compute its content?".

Comment: Thank you Michael... great advice, I will try and change my attitude towards XSLT development